# U does not name a type - template compilation error

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, member-functions, class-template

Here is my simple program. I tried forcing the `static_cast` so that the compiler knows that `U` is nothing but `int`. However, still, the template cannot instantiate the int version of my function `Add`.

In the future, I want to extend this template so that `U` and `V` are of different types and my program still works.

However, currently, even the same type is not working. What am I missing here?

What is the reason for the compilation error?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename U>
class Addable
{
    U x;
public:
    Addable(U val) : x{ val } { cout << "Constructor called" << endl; }
    template <typename T>
    U add(T y);
};

U Addable::add(T y)
{
    x += y;
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    Addable<int> A{ 10 };
    int x = A.add(static_cast<int>(10));
    cout << x;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As a side note: Your `static_cast` is irrelevant to the issue, what you have.  Also, have a look [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 4):

Your template member function's definition is wrong.
When you define the template member function of a template class, you need to specify the both template parameters as follows:

```
template <typename U>
template <typename T>
U Addable<U>::add(T y)
{
    x += y;
    return x;
}
```

[live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5oW4sza9v)

Answer (score 0):

In order to define a template function outside of a template class. The correct one should be

```
template <typename U> template <typename T>
U Addable<U>::add(T y)
{
   x += y;
   return x;
}
```